# can you add a electron to sodium?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ions

if you have a sodium+1 ion, are you able to add one electron some way to make it back to a neutral sodium atom?

Comment: Yes, electrolysis of molten salt will produce sodium metal and chlorine gas.

Comment: Maybe you should also ask "how to add" and clarify what do you mean by "add" in the solid state system or in a liquid solution or in an atom, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The process is called *reduction* and it happens all the time. It's really considered chemistry rather than physics. How do you think sodium metal is made? It's not found like that in nature (remember how it reacts with water?).

If you google "making sodium metal" you will get lots of hits. See for example [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=seSg_GWj1b0) - there, they use magnesium powder as the reducing agent. The magnesium "wants" the oxygen more than the sodium.

Answer (score -1):

Well if an electron is added to sodium it would want to absorb and even release some energy. Just never happens in nature because most materials are more reactive than sodium and never give electron to sodium. It can happen, but it rarely happens.